# multiple devices, single driver

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, pci

I have developped a linux device driver for a PCI-e fpga card, and it's working. 
Now, let's suppose that I would like to install two (equal) of these pci-e card on the same pc. 
how does it work? I tried to insmod the driver, I expected a "double probing" callback but it wasn't. So, how can i manage this situation? by the minor number? could someone help me?

ps
the pci card are fpga development board, so they are actually "the same" card, maybe I have to differentiate something in the hw?

Comment: How does the driver recognize the card?  If the possibility exists for several identical cards to be present at once, the driver should see if it has already initialized itself and skip any cards already enabled.  It can register to receive several IRQs (for example) and map multiple memory areas for access.  The easiest thing for the ISR to do is scan all enabled registers to see if there is anything to do.

Comment: The cards are differentiated by their slot. Your PCI driver's `.probe` callback should be called twice.

Answer (score 0):

The situation will be different in case your driver is built-in instead of a kernel module to load. Try to compile it as a built-in driver and make sure that your cards are both powered ON. In that way, both of your cards will be enumerated, then probed by the same driver.

The fact that you insmod the driver, in that case, it relies on the code itself and the way you wrote your driver. If you can share the driver, I would be helpful.